# How do I see error messages generated in PowerShell event handlers?

Tags: powershell, events, error-handling, console

Normally PowerShell errors are shown in the console in red text.  You can test this using `Write-Error 'This is an example non-terminating error message.'`:

[image: red-text error message screenshot]

Errors inside the scriptblock called by an event, however, do not show the same errors on the console.  This script demonstrates this phenomenon:

```
$id='MyTimerEvent'
$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$n=0

$callback= { 
    $Script:n++
    Write-Host "TIMER: Count $n"
    if($n -eq 2){
        Write-Host "The next line should be a non-terminating error message."
        Write-Error "This is the error message."
    }
    if($n -gt 3){
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $id
    }
}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -SourceIdentifier $id `
                     -EventName Elapsed -Action $callback

$timer.Interval=500
$timer.AutoReset=$true
$timer.Enabled=$true
```

The script's output is as follows:

```
TIMER: Count 1 
TIMER: Count 2 
This line should be followed by a a non-terminating error message. 
TIMER: Count 3 
TIMER: Count 4
```

Note that output from the line `Write-Error "This is the error message."` is not shown in the console.  PowerShell [seems to support the concept of redirecting output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) but it seems more geared toward redirecting to text files.

**How do I direct errors produced in PowerShell event handlers to the PowerShell console?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap the entire contents of the block in a redirection to Write-Host, it works.

```
$callback = {(&{
  // ...
}) 2>&1 | Write-Host}
```

This uses the regular ("success") stream internally to keep track of all that stuff, then shoves it all to the actual console instead of throwing it away as I expect events normally do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full solution to output both terminating *and* non-terminating errors, and also errors *only*.

```
$callback = {
    # wrap and invoke script block
    (& {
        # insert an empty trap to make the script block
        # output terminating errors too
        trap { }      
        Write-Error "non-terminating error"
        throw "terminating error"
    # redirect error-stream (2) to success-stream (1)
    }) 2>&1 |
    # filter errors only
    where {$_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]} |
    # write to console directly (because output-stream is ignored)
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'Red'
}
```